# Eclipse - how do I reference a particular class in a project from the dependent project?

Tags: java, eclipse, opengl, jogl

I have followed the steps from the jogamp wikia on installing JOGL in Eclipse (https://jogamp.org/wiki/index.php/Setting_up_a_JogAmp_project_in_your_favorite_IDE). I have already set the JOGL project on my project's build path. How do I reference a particular class from the JOGL project in my project?

For example: I want to call the Binary64 class from inside my project. How do I correctly form the input statement? (the path from inside the JOGL project would be JOGL/jogl-all.jar/com.jogamp.opengl.math/Binary64.class)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Check if it's already in your classpath. That guarantee you added your Jar correctly
2. Type `Binary64` and combine `Ctrl + Space` to auto declare required Jar file into your `.java` file